# How does pooling work with crossed effects in multilevel models?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

In Section 12.2 of [Gelman and Hill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X), The authors mention that one of the main benefits of creating a multi-level model is that you can take advantage of "partial pooling". As an example, if you were creating a two-level hierarchical model of test scores by state and county, then each county's predicted estimate would be a *weighted average* of that county's average test score and the overall state's score.

In more complex models, I've seen additional random effects added. For example, a model might contain state, county, gender, and race. In this case, the model is no longer strictly hierarchical, and we now have crossed effects.

In this case,

1) I assume the effect of county is still based on a pooled estimate. Are the effects of gender and race still being pooled in some way? If so, how?

2) Would this model be considered a two-level model or a four-level model?

edit: For clarification, the data for race and gender in this example would be at the individual level (they are not county or state-level characteristics).

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question about race. If you are talking about individuals within the county, within the state, you are adding levels to your model. If you are talking about race and gender in terms of county estimates, you are not adding levels. The main thing is to determine your unit of analysis and then the hierarchical structure of the groups associated with that unit.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the Gelman and Hill book at the moment. However, the normal meaning of "partial pooling" simply refers to a model with random effects. It is "partial" pooling because (in the case of random intercepts) each subject has their own intercept (often assumed to be normally distributed across subjects) plus the additional group level mean estimate.

The number of levels in a mixed / multilevel model is determined by the levels of nesting. If your unit of measurement is individuals, and they are nested within counties, and counties are nested within states, then you have a 3-level model. The addition of gender and race does not affect this (because they are measured at the individual level. If you had states nested within countries, then you would have a 4-level model.